# Como utilizar props no styled-components?

Tags: react, styled-components

Gostaria de utilizar `props` em um `attr` de um componente no [styled-components](https://styled-components.com/), ou seja:

```
export const Button = styled.input.attrs({
    type: 'button',
    value: `${props => props.value}`
})`
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    font-weight: 800;
    color: black;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 5%;
    min-width: 120px;
    height: 35px;
    margin: 50px;
    cursor: pointer;
`
```

Porém quando eu invoco este componente com

```
<Button value={'submit'}/>
```

é retornado o valor literal ou seja ele cria um botão contendo como `value` um "props => props.value" invés do "submit".

Como resolver esse problema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Está usando o [styled-components](https://styled-components.com/) de maneira errada, não precisa passar para dentro os `props` `value` é só passar o valor que esse propriedade já existe, ***exemplo***:

```
import styled from 'styled-components';

export const Button = styled.input.attrs(props => ({
  type: 'button',  
}))`
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    font-weight: 800;
    color: black;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 5%;
    min-width: 120px;
    height: 35px;
    margin: 50px;
    cursor: pointer;
`;

export default Button;
```

e na hora de utilizar:

```
<Button value={"Submit"} />
```

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Claro que utilizar `props` no [styled-components](https://styled-components.com/) é uma prática muito utilizada, mas, está usando de uma maneira que não terá resultado, por exemplo quero criar um `<button/>` com cores diferentes o código basicamente:

```
const Btn = styled.button`
  background: ${(props) => props.color};
  color: ${(props) => props.colorText};
  height: 30px;
  width: 150px;
`;
```

utilizando da seguinte forma:

```
<Btn color={'red'} colorText={'white'}>
    Color
</Btn>

export default Btn;
```

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

<sup>**Referencia:** [styled-components](https://styled-components.com/)</sup>